# WPF: binding, conditional property setter

Tags: wpf

I have a property that is populated via binding. Color attribute is set the value of Color property

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
       <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Color}"/>
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

How can I refactor that to the conditional  binding like that:

```
   <Rectangle.Fill>
           <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=SomeBooleanProperty ? #FF0000 : #00FF00 }"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thank you, @Jackson, final code is the following:

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="ColorBySuccess">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Success}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#00FF00"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
...
<Rectangle Fill="Green" Style="{StaticResource ColorBySuccess}" .../>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this for changing style based on any of the properties of the control:

```
<Style x:Key="SwitchStyle" TargetType="Switch">
            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{StaticResource LightGray}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger TargetType="Switch" Property="IsToggled" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger TargetType="Switch" Property="IsToggled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkGray}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: this worked, but I had to remove TargetType="Switch" from both <Trigger> tags, otherwise compiler was complaining